# custom barbuttonItem doesn't show up

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uinavigationitem

I have made a custom bar button item at my navigation controller and it was working fine but it doesn't anymore.
This is the lines that I use to make the custom bar button :

```
 func addSlideMenuButton(){
        let btnShowMenu = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
        //btnShowMenu.setImage(self.defaultMenuImage(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btnShowMenu.setImage(UIImage(named: "barBtnMenu"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btnShowMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        btnShowMenu.addTarget(self, action: "onSlideMenuButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        let customBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnShowMenu)
       // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
         self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
    }
```

the image exists and there is no error or crash .

Even If I add the bar button item from soryboard , When I run the application it would hidden my bar button item.

What could be wrong ?

Comment: Maybe because of the `tintColor` it's becoming 'invisible'?

Comment: @Islam Q no it doesn't . I double check it by clicking on the button area and there is no button there at all

Answer (score 0):

```
func addSlideMenuButton() {

    let customBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "barBtnMenu"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "onSlideMenuButtonPressed")
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options come to mind

- Are you sure you're not setting `navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true` anywhere in that UIViewController?
- Are you sure you're not adding another UINavigationBar on top of the one provided by the system?